# create a combo box dymically fom list in a viewmodel 9+ mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, combobox

I have in my ViewModel a list that contain 2 ou 3 values:

```
public class person
{
   List<string> civility{get;set;}
   string nom  {get;set;}
   sting prenom  {get;set;}
}
```

how can i create a combobox in the view mapped to civility property. Sometimes we show combobox if the list  contain 2 values et sometimes 3 if the list contains 3 and obtain the value in submit

Comment: Your question is not clear. For proper select list that posts back to a property, you need *two pieces*: a data source for the select list and a property to store the *chosen* value from the select list. If you post back to the same property you got your select list from, then you'll overwrite your select list.

Comment: I need to show List<string> civility{get;set;} as a combox in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's technically as easy as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FieldName", Model.civility.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m, Text = m }));
```

You'll end up with something akin to:

```
<select id="FieldName" name="FieldName">
    <option value="CivilityItem1">CivilityItem1</option>
    ...
</select>
```

If you want it tied to an actual property on your model (you'll need to add the property to your model first)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCivility, Model.civility.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m, Text = m }))
```

Comment: i need a comboboxList and not a dropDownList

Comment: Drop down list == combobox == select box. It's all different names for the same thing. The only difference would be if you wanted a multiple select, in which case you would use `Html.ListBoxFor`

Comment: @ChrisPratt: thanks for pointing to ListBoxFor, I spent several hours trying to workaround it before learning this function exists. It's not easy to google it out unless you happen to know how is multiple select called in MVC.